# How can I add a Button to my wear OS app?

Tags: android, button, wear-os

I am adding a Button to my first Wear OS application. When I follow a model from
my existing Android applications, there appears to be difference due to
"WearableActivity" versus "Activity". I cannot define the OnClickListener.

In my on create is this:

```
bottomButton = findViewById(R.id.bottomButton);
        setListener();
```

later in the main activity source is this

```
void setListener()
    {
            bottomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) // toggle between report and graph display
            {   if (showGraph)
                    {showReport=true; showGraph=false;bottomButton.setText("show Report");}
                else
                    {showReport=false;showGraph=true;bottomButton.setText("show Graph");}



            }  // end, onClick
        }); // end, setOnClickListener
    } // end, setListener()
```

In both cases the button is defined in XML and found and used as follows

```
OkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OkButton);
OkButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: is this correct:  
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              
                
               //functional code here
        });

Comment: it should be. did you try it out?

Comment: Shark it does compile anyway. And I can access the items in the button such as text. But when I change the text, it doesn't appear on the screen. And when I push the button in the emulator, it doesn't register any action.

Comment: Your clickListener for your bottomButton looks good. For OkButton OnClickListener has been set to `this` which requires you to implement the View.OnClickListener interface in your activity.

Answer (score 4):

> it does compile anyway. And I can access the items in the button such as text. But when I change the text, it doesn't appear on the screen. And when I push the button in the emulator, it doesn't register any action.

The problem is not from your code but from the Android wear emulator. Your wear emulator is in the ambient(low power) mode. Click in the top of the emulator window to toggle between interactive(full power) and ambient modes(low power).

[image]

> How can I define and use a button in the wear os application.

The same way it is done on the mobile side. Below is an example

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button clickMeButton;
    TextView textView;
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setAmbientEnabled();

        clickMeButton = findViewById(R.id.click_me_button);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.test_textview);
        clickMeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        count++;
        textView.setText("I am clicked: "+count);
    }


    @Override
    public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails) {
        // Handle entering ambient mode
        super.onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails);
        Log.e("Hello", "I'm ambient");
    }

    @Override
    public void onExitAmbient() {
        // Handle exiting ambient mode
        super.onExitAmbient();
        Log.e("Hello", "exit ambient");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateAmbient() {
        // Update the content
        super.onUpdateAmbient();
        Log.e("Hello", "update ambient: " + isAmbient());
    }

}
```

Below is the results of the above activity (NB: Click in the top of the emulator window to toggle between interactive and ambient modes):

[image]

**EDIT**

To avoid implementing View.OnClickListener in your activity you can pass an instance of View.OnClickListener when calling `setOnClickListener` for the `OkButton` like you are already doing for the `bottomButton`.

```
OkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                //do something when OkButton is clicked
            } 
        });
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problems

Comment: Hi. I get error message after adding "implements View.OnClickListener" to my main activity definition. It says 
"Class MainActivity must either be  declared abstract or implement abstract method onclick(View) in OnClickListener" which I admit flies right over my  head.

Comment: I will work thru your codes today and see if that helps it. thank you.

Comment: @user1644002 just implement the method it demands: `@Override public void onClick(View view) {}`.

Comment: Just as @Martin rightly suggested, you need to implement the `onClick(View view)` method and add the logic you want to run when the button is clicked in that method. See the example in the answer.

Comment: I have reworked my code to match the example better. When I click the button I am seeing:  

Dropping event due to no window focus .....
Cancelling event due to no window focus:.....

every click I see this pair of messages

There is no trigger when I set a break point inside the onClick routine

Comment: That's because your wear emulator is in ambient mode. Look at the first part of the answer for how to toggle it out of ambient mode to interactive mode

Comment: You could also see the gif at the bottom part of the answer to see how button click starts responding after toggling the wear emulator out of ambient mode

Comment: The emulator seems to use the power button to sleep/wake the watch, there is no result from clicking on the title bar of the emulator. When I toggle the power button on, then the button visibly changes when I press it. And the ignored message does not appear. When I toggle the power button off, then the ignored message appears again.  The emulator doesn't show any hint if it is in low power or high power mode.

Comment: Yes you can can use the power button on the emulator's side menu to achieve the same feat (toggle between lower power and high power modes)

Comment: If you want to see how emulator is being toggle between the two modes, you can put breakpoints inside the methods `public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails)` and `public void onExitAmbient()` in your Activity. Click on the power button and observe how the breakpoints are being triggered.

Comment: OK I am going to recreate your demo app intact to see what's going on with my code thanks very much

Comment: I am accepting your solution, it works when I run it . My app still needs to be fixed, it was originally built without androidx, I will rebuild it from scratch and try to get it working with the button. thank you again

Comment: I had to place the setOnClickListener code at the end of my onResume code. When there was just a onCreate life cycle entry, the setOnClick worked fine in there. As I completed the coding of my app, and added onResume (which is my workhorse) then the button stopped working until I placed the setOnClickListener there. I don't get it.

Comment: let's continue this here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203852/room-for-networks-and-user1644002